# Is Unity already preinstalled inside ubuntu netbook edition?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook

is it Unity already preinstalled inside ubuntu netbook edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity is the default interface for Ubuntu Netbook Edition 10.10, older versions of the Netbook Edition (10.04 and earlier) do not use Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is(since 10.10 maverick meerkat), but beware, this is not the same version that will be used in desktop  version in 11.04 Natty Narwall.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is with 10.10 maverick meekat